# Display GIT SHA on Jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm a Jenkins noob. I'd like to display the GIT commit hash when a Jenkins deployment job completes.

Purpose: our QA team needs to see this hash so that they can determine which commit they are testing on in the website. Providing an application number doesn't provide the same value, as they cannot correlate it to anything in GIT.

Here are a couple of approaches that would work, but I don't know how to implement:

- Slack notification that contains the GIT SHA after successful publish
- Build log contains the GIT SHA
- Text file/html file is generated with the latest SHA

I've noticed a few different options to include GIT variables inside the Jenkins build process, but so far I haven't had any luck populating those variables.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The GIT plugin sets a number of environment variables including GIT_COMMIT which should contain the SHA. You can easily print this variable in your build log (assuming it's not already printed there - I use SVN rather than GIT). I use Groovy a lot, so if you have the groovy plugin installed, you can just add a groovy script build step with this line in it:

```
println "GIT SHA: " + build.getEnvironment(listener).get('GIT_COMMIT')
```

If you want to make the SHA more easily accessible, you may want to consider making the SHA a part of the build name. You can accomplish this with the [Build Name Setter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) plugin. You could set your build name something like this `#${BUILD_NUMBER}.${GIT_COMMIT}`